# How to archive URLs with special chars with wget on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, wget

I'm trying to archive a website but wget isn't linking some URLs to local files, the URLs that aren't linked to local files contain "´" and "²" to give some examples. The URL of those two examples are like this:

`https://www.website.com/X6XNjEzNzYzX-bob%EF%BF%BDs-burgers-s10e07.html`
`https://www.website.com/X6XNjEzNzY4X-50-m%C2%B2-2021-s01.html`

The htmls are saved with these filenames:

`X6XNjEzNzYzX-bobÂs-burgers-s10e07.html`
`X6XNjEzNzY4X-50-mÂ²-2021-s01.html`

But the index file doesn't link them, they link to their real URL.

This is the wget command:

`wget.exe --tries=5 --restrict-file-names=windows --continue --timestamping --no-check-certificate --recursive --level=2 --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --trust-server-names --force-directories --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" "https://www.website.com/?pg=1"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for this. I had to add the command:

`--local-encoding=UTF-8`

This solved the problem.